# Pause AnimationDrawable and resume

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I would like to use an animated drawable to pause and
Resume from that frame.

<https: //developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable>

I also referred to the URL above, but SETVisible () starts animation from the beginning.

I looked at other things, but the contents were covered and could not be used as a reference.

Is there a way to pause using an image in the animation list?

'''

```
           s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               chip1 = chip1 - point;
               chip.setText1("chip : " + chip1);

               animationDrawable1.start();
               animationDrawable2.start();
               animationDrawable3.start();
               animationDrawable4.start();
               animationDrawable5.start();
               animationDrawable6.start();
               animationDrawable7.start();
               animationDrawable8.start();
               animationDrawable9.start();

               Thread thread;
               if(v == s) {
                   stopRun = false;
                   thread = new Thread(String.valueOf(this));
                   thread.start();

                   //開始時間の取得
                   starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
               }

               b1.setEnabled(true);
               b2.setEnabled(true);
               b3.setEnabled(true);
               s.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           }
        });

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                animationDrawable1.stop();
                animationDrawable4.stop();
                animationDrawable7.stop();

                animationDrawable1.setVisible(false,false);
                animationDrawable4.setVisible(false,false);
                animationDrawable7.setVisible(false,false);

                stopRun = true;

                run();

                droidImage1.setImageResource(getID1((int1)n));    //droidImage1に乱数で決まった数字に当たる画像をセットする
                droidImage4.setImageResource(getID1((int1)n1));
                droidImage7.setImageResource(getID1((int1)n2));

                b1.setEnabled(false);   //ボタンを押せなくする
                if(b1.isEnabled() == false && b2.isEnabled() == false && b3.isEnabled() == false) { //ボタンがすべて押されたときjudgeメソッドを呼び出す
                    judge();
                }
            }
        });

        });
```

'''

Below is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/star"
        android:duration="120"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: I edited it, but is there anything still?

Comment: I see, I understand. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Thanks for gracefully accepting my feedback. Good style. (Sorry that I am unable to vote on your improved question. I simply lack the technical understanding.)

Comment: It's okay. Thank you for your advice